# is there any apps available to write math expressions?

Tags: math-software

is there any apps available to write math expressions?
Its getting difficult for me to write the math expressions in my questions. Please suggest me is there any such app..thank u

Comment: Learn the easy directions to MathJaX. It usually appears on the right side in this page, on "Featured on Meta" .

Comment: Texpad is quite good, and very much in further development.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference